# iOS custom Framework: Can't find symbols?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've created a custom framework using Xcode (new->target->ios->framework/library->cocoa touch framework). The framework contains some classes, images and a xib file.

I've also created another project to test the framework. However when I'm trying to instantiate a class from the framework to use it in the test project it gives me:

> "_OBJ C_CLASS_$_InitialViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Which is wired, because I've some classes in the framework that I can use without any issues...

Any suggestions on how to resolve or further debug the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you remembered to make the `InitialViewController.h` header file public? Select the file in the project navigator on the left, then in the file inspector panel ensure the target membership dropdown menu shows "Public".

Additionally, ensure the `.m` file is also set to be compiled with your framework target. Under target membership, ensure that the checkbox is ticked next to your framework target.